# Visual Studio 2019 #c Redirect Not Working on process.start file cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/"); I am a beginner so I dont know much about visual studio and C#  [Error Message Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kniiV.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start is used to run executable code, so you need to pass it an executable. For example:

```
// the @ escapes the backslash characters in the path to the Chrome executable
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe", "http://www.youtube.com");
```

Depending on how (or if) Chrome is installed on your system, you may even be able to just run:

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://www.youtube.com");
```

Comment: Using the Shell, you can start the program associated with a file extension, or a protocol, as far as there's a Registry entry that allows it. So, something like: `var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("https://www.youtube.com") { UseShellExecute = true }; Process.Start(psi);` (in .Net Core and .Net 5+ `UseShellExecute = false` by default) -- If there's no default Browser (in this case) for that protocol and more than one WebBrowser is installed, the app picker is shown to the User.